# ASP.NET change SessionID

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies, global-asax, sessionid

i must change the SessionID for an ASP.NET 4.0 Application (SessionID via Cookies) to have it run on 2 domains with the same Session (http://web1.local and http://web2.local). This will keep the Items in sync abov the 2 domains.

Therefor the Page will have iframes with an "setkey.aspx/ashx", which must set the new SessionID.

```
<iframe src="http://web1.local/SetKey.aspx?sid=<%=Session.SessionID%>" width="250" height="100"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://web2.local/SetKey.aspx?sid=<%=Session.SessionID%>" width="250" height="100"></iframe>
```

In the Session.Start the Session is already filled, so the SessionID keeps static via several Requests from the same Broeser.

I found several Posts, which mostly uses the SessionIDManager.SaveSessionID, but i could get none of them working.

i found this code, but where do i have to call it? (global.asax / default.aspx / setjey.aspx/ashx?)

```
Dim Redirected As Boolean = False
Dim Added As Boolean = False

Dim SID = Request.QueryString("sid")
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(SID) AndAlso SID.Length = 24 Then
    Dim SM As New SessionIDManager
    SM.InitializeRequest(HttpContext.Current, False, True)
    SM.RemoveSessionID(HttpContext.Current)
    SM.SaveSessionID(HttpContext.Current, SID, Redirected, Added)
End If
```

Did anyone got this code to run correctly?

Comment: Would using a SQL State Server be an option?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604

Comment: Hi, no, as SQL Server would cost to much performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried simply setting the cookie in Global.asax 's `Application_EndRequest` handler and it works. Here's in C#, but you get the idea...

```
void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
   ctx.Response.Cookies.Remove("ASP.NET_SessionId");
   ctx.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ctx.Request.QueryString("sid")));
}
```

Comment: the EndRequest was the only methos i didnt try :-) Thank You!

Comment: It's working in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera but not in IE9 :-(

Comment: Mmm... My guess is IE is making it read-only. Try changing the cookie name to something else (e.g. SessionID) by adding  `cookieName="SessoinID" to the `<sessionState>` tag in your web.config file. That should fix IE. Don't forget to change the code accordingly.

Comment: Hi Diego, changing the cookiename did not work :-( I uploaded my Testapp to http://sdrv.ms/wvYbjW maybe anyone has a idea how to get this working for ie9.